# Obtener elementos dentro de dos índices en un array

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente array

`["unranked" => 0, "iron4" => 1, "iron3" => 1, "iron2" => 1, "iron1" => 1, "bronze4" => 3, "bronze3" => 3, "bronze2" => 3, "bronze1" => 3, "silver4" => 4, "silver3" => 4, "silver2" => 4, "silver1" => 4, "gold4" => 5.5, "gold3" => 5.5, "gold2" => 5.5, "gold1" => 5.5, "platinum4" => 7, "platinum3" => 7, "platinum2" => 7, "platinum1" => 7, "diamond4" => 9, "diamond3" => 9, "diamond2" => 9, "diamond1" => 9]`

Y quiero obtener los elementos que estén desde **bronze4** hasta **silver4** por ejemplo.

Comment: Y qué es lo que has intentado?

Comment: @VickMuñoz array_slice(), que me habían recomendado anteriormente, pero al notar que retornaba valores erróneos, leí la documentación y me di cuenta de que no es lo que necesito y no se me ocurre nada, tengo en claro lo que hay que hacer, pero no cómo hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Seguro se puede optimizar más pero bueno di con el resultado, esto imprime `array(5) { ["bronze4"]=> int(3) ["bronze3"]=> int(3) ["bronze2"]=> int(3) ["bronze1"]=> int(3) ["silver4"]=> int(4) }`, espero te funcione :), cualquier duda hazla saber.

```
$miarray = array("unranked" => 0, "iron4" => 1, "iron3" => 1, "iron2" => 1, "iron1" => 1, "bronze4" => 3, "bronze3" => 3, "bronze2" => 3, "bronze1" => 3, "silver4" => 4, "silver3" => 4, "silver2" => 4, "silver1" => 4, "gold4" => 5.5, "gold3" => 5.5, "gold2" => 5.5, "gold1" => 5.5, "platinum4" => 7, "platinum3" => 7, "platinum2" => 7, "platinum1" => 7, "diamond4" => 9, "diamond3" => 9, "diamond2" => 9, "diamond1" => 9);

    $elemento = 'bronze4';
$elemento2 = 'silver4';


$primero = 0;
$segundo = 0;

foreach ($miarray as $key => $value) {

    //echo $value;
    if ($key == $elemento) {

        $nuevo = array_slice($miarray, $primero);

        foreach ($nuevo as $keyNuevo => $valueNuevo) {
                if ($keyNuevo == $elemento2) {
                    //echo $segundo;

                    $final =  array_slice($nuevo, 0,$segundo);
                        var_dump($final);

                }
        }


    }
$segundo++;
$primero++;
}
```

Comment: Y como se puede obtener el valor que éste brinda?

Comment: `array(5) { ["bronze4"]=> int(3) ["bronze3"]=> int(3) ["bronze2"]=> int(3) ["bronze1"]=> int(3) ["silver4"]=> int(4) }` Cómo obtendrías por ejemplo el valor de **bronze4**, pues fácil `$final['bronze4']` el valor obtenido sería el 3, deberías de leer un poco más sobre [array asociativo](https://diego.com.es/arrays-asociativos-en-php).

Comment: Ah eso si sé, no vi bien tu script, muchas gracias, mirá abajo mi autosolución

Comment: @EstebanFernández sí, ya la vi, si te funciona así adelante, yo lo hice de esa forma para encontrar el indice de los elementos de donde querías partir, si lo pones estático pues es más simple.

Comment: Claro, me había olvidado de aclarar eso, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo acabo de solucionar, al parecer hay que obtener la posición de cada index y hacer uso de la función **array_slice()**

```
return array_slice($inicio, $fin - $inicio);
```

Como la posición de fin será un número mayor al del inicio, se los resta en el siguiente orden para evitar problemas